# Facebook ad campaign source attribution - what tags to look for?

Tags: facebook, ads

I am working on figuring out our source attribution for a Facebook ad campaign that we're running for our game. As part of the campaign we have a low-level ad buy going on in the right-side ad bar, which averages several hundred clicks and several hundred installs per day. The problem is when we look at our source attribution within the app, we don't see "facebook:ad" passed nearly as often as it should. It seems like the source attribution is being given to some other source, like the appcenter or canvas. Can anyone shed some light on how they have tracked ad campaign acquisitions and installs for their Facebook app?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What parameters are you including in the URL you're promoting? Are you specifying the 'url tags' in the ads to differentiate the traffic from the sponsored posts from those which are not sponsored?

Answer (score 1):

What analytics package are you using for your app? Also, what OS is your game written for?

If you are using Google Analytics, using Google Analytics URL Builder will allow you to tag each ad's attributes such as position and content before they get to your app. Use this in conjunction with [Android SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns#google-play-implement) to see where people are finding you before they go to the store and download/install.

If you're using iOS take a look at the [iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/campaigns#measurement)

The Apple App Store does not currently support campaign measurement using Google Analytics. However, custom URL schemes can be used in conjunction with general campaign measurement to pass campaign information into your iOS app after it has been downloaded and installed.

You may also want to look at apsalar.com as they have a free source attribution solution for Facebook.

Hope that helps

Matt